# android studio keeps giving me message "Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

Tags: java, android, xml

i dont know what the problem is. I dont know if it is the image that i am using or there is just a misspelled word.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    < RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.jam7733.myapplication.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/initialappdesign">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
            android:src="#fd0000" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the " " before your `RelativeLayout` fixe it

```
< RelativeLayout
```

To

```
<RelativeLayout
```